# How to measure Windows Azure bandwidth usage programmatically?

Tags: azure

I'm running a Windows Azure web application (ASP.Net MVC).

How do I measure the bandwidth used by it from within the code?

I have more than one user for the same web app and I would like to limit how much each user is allowed to consume in terms of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure SDK doesn't provide any billing or consumption information programatically. As lgorek stated, you can approximate usage with IIS And WCF performance counters.And you'll also be able to use your own logging to track traffic from different users.  However, you won't be able to track bandwidth consumed when users download content from blob storage. Well, you could, but only if all of your blobs were private and you streamed their content through your web application instead of direct links on your web pages .

Comment: My blob items are currently public. Is there any downside to making them private in terms of serving speed or cost?

Comment: Since I provided this answer, things have changed. There are now Storage Metrics and logging, so you can now discover blob usage - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-metrics-using-metrics-to-track-storage-usage.aspx.

Comment: Regarding the public- vs private-blob question: If you make blobs private, you can still provide public access via Shared Access Signature. In this scenario, there shouldn't be a perf difference. If they're private AND traffic routes through your Web Role via IIS, then yes, there will be some type of perf hit, as you're taxing IIS and relying on bandwidth between your Web Role and Storage.

Answer (score 1):

So, it is possible to use performance counters to store the network traffic size. However, it sounds like you want to capture custom traffic bandwidth size. If its by user, you'll likely want to create custom trace or other code that takes username of the current user into account

Comment: I have a single code base that serves content to more than one domain name. It's a CMS running in Windows Azure and each website uses the same code in Windows Azure. For each website, I would like to measure how much has been downloaded by anyone. Each website is public facing and can be used by all internet users. Is a performance counter going to give me that information or do I need something more custom?