# are there any way to monitor the data usage of CloudStorageAccount (Azure SDK)

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Do there exist any way to monitor the data usages of CloudStorageAccount in the Azure SDK? If possible also the number of requests as this is the two things defining the price.

I would like to show a little indication of the cost using my application.

Comment: It sounds like you want to query the analytics table(s) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windowsazure/hh343264.aspx

Comment: From a quick look i got the impression that this was was the account overall. I would like to show it as session based number in my application. I will take a look again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590682/how-to-measure-windows-azure-bandwidth-usage-programmatically seems related